# How to call function from SwiftUI component when generic property changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI component whose state needs to be reset when one of its properties changes. However, to keep the component as generic as possible I want that property to be generic, i.e., `let someProperty: any Equatable`.

**My initial attempt was:**

```
struct MyMenu: View {
    let items: [MenuItem]
    let resetOnChange: any Equatable

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                // scroll view content
            }
            .onChange(of: resetOnChange) { _ {
                if let first = items.first {
                    proxy.scrollTo(first, anchor: .leading)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this approach seems to cause an issue with the `View` not knowing a concrete type. Ultimately resulting in an error on the line of `ScrollViewReader`, "Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'"

An approach that **did** work, was to define a generic in the component:

```
struct MyMenu<ResetParameter: Equatable>: View {
    ....

    let resetOnChange: ResetParameter

    ...
}

// Ex. where User is an Equatable model.
let menu = MyMenu<User>(items: photoCategories, resetOnChange: viewModel.user)
```

The problem I have with this is that this type declaration is now required (we may want to use this menu in the future w/o a reset parameter). Not only that, it makes initializing the menu confusing. For example, if I want the reset parameter to be an unrelated type ... i.e., `User`. This results in the menu looking like it's a user menu, when in fact the menu shows different photo categories. The only relation of `User` is that we want the menu to reset if the `User` model changes.

Another approach I tried was using `AnyPublisher<Void, Never>` (instead of an Equatable property) and then using `.onReceive(..)` instead of `onChange(...)`. The problem there is that `onReceive` was called far more often than expected.

One thing to note: This doesn't work using `items` as the change because their values often stay the same from `User` to `User`, so runtime doesn't see them as actually changing.

Is there a clean way to do this, or am I stuck with the less-than-ideal working solution I found above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI requires concrete types for just about everything, especially when it comes to Views.

A more versatile solution to generics is using `where` to declare the required conformance. It allows for the type to be determine on `init`

```
struct MyMenu<E>: View where E: Equatable{
    let items: [MenuItem]
    let resetOnChange: E
    
    init(items: [MenuItem], resetOnChange: E) {
        self.items = items
        self.resetOnChange = resetOnChange
    }
    
    init(items: [MenuItem]) where E == String {
        self.items = items
        self.resetOnChange = "" //Nothing from parent just set to blank
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                // scroll view content
            }
            .onChange(of: resetOnChange) { _ in
                if let first = items.first {
                    proxy.scrollTo(first, anchor: .leading)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or make it optional and set to `nil`

```
struct MyMenu<E>: View where E: Equatable{
    let items: [MenuItem]
    let resetOnChange: E?
    
    init(items: [MenuItem], resetOnChange: E) {
        self.items = items
        self.resetOnChange = resetOnChange
    }
    
    init(items: [MenuItem]) where E == Optional<String> {
        self.items = items
        self.resetOnChange = nil
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                // scroll view content
            }
            .onChange(of: resetOnChange) { _ in
                if let first = items.first {
                    proxy.scrollTo(first, anchor: .leading)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics#Generic-Where-Clauses

Comment: This is likely the best solution considering current limitations. Thanks for your help and link to the docs, much appreciated :D